# Как применять функцию только к текущему элементу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрытый блок у 10 товаров (лежат в li).

HTML:

```
<li>
<img src="">
<p class="price">8999</p>
<p class="tooltip-beauty">show beauty box</p>
<span class="short">
    <div class="tooltip-beauty-box">Some Text</div>
</span> 
</li>

<li>
<img src="">
<p class="price">8999</p>
<p class="tooltip-beauty">show beauty box</p>
<span class="short">
    <div class="tooltip-beauty-box">Some Text</div>
</span> 
</li>

<li>
<img src="">
<p class="price">8999</p>
<p class="tooltip-beauty">show beauty box</p>
<span class="short">
    <div class="tooltip-beauty-box">Some Text</div>
</span> 
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('.tooltip-beauty').hover(
    function(){
        $('.tooltip-beauty-box').fadeIn();
        //console.log(list);
    },

    function(){
        $('.tooltip-beauty-box').fadeOut();

    });
});
```

Логично, что сейчас при наведении на кнопку блок всплывает у всех элементов, в которых он присутствует. Нужно, чтобы появлялся только на текущем (как hover в сss).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы в функциях используете селектор, а с this мы будем показывать и скрывать только те `tooltip-beauty-box` которые находятся рядом с элементом на который вы навели

```js
$(function($){

  $('.tooltip-beauty').hover(
   function(){
      element = $(this).parent().find('.tooltip-beauty-box');
      if(element.css('display') != 'block'){
        element.fadeIn();
      }
   },
   function(){
      element = $(this).parent().find('.tooltip-beauty-box');
      if(element.css('display') != 'none'){
        element.fadeOut();
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.tooltip-beauty-box{
display: none;
}

.tooltip-beauty{
background: gray;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
<img src="">
<p class="price">8999</p>
<p class="tooltip-beauty">show beauty box</p>
<span class="short">
    <div class="tooltip-beauty-box">Some Text</div>
</span> 
</li>

<li>
<img src="">
<p class="price">8999</p>
<p class="tooltip-beauty">show beauty box</p>
<span class="short">
    <div class="tooltip-beauty-box">Some Text</div>
</span> 
</li>

<li>
<img src="">
<p class="price">8999</p>
<p class="tooltip-beauty">show beauty box</p>
<span class="short">
    <div class="tooltip-beauty-box">Some Text</div>
</span> 
</li>
```

Добавил небольшую проверку, что бы элемент не моргал при частом срабатывании события hover

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($){

    $('.tooltip-beauty').hover(
    function(){
       $(this).next().find('.tooltip-beauty-box').fadeIn();
        //console.log(list);
    },

    function(){
       $(this).next().find('.tooltip-beauty-box').fadeOut();

    });
});
```

```css
.tooltip-beauty-box{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
<img src="">
<p class="price">8999</p>
<p class="tooltip-beauty">show beauty box</p>
<span class="short">
    <div class="tooltip-beauty-box">Some Text</div>
</span> 
</li>

<li>
<img src="">
<p class="price">8999</p>
<p class="tooltip-beauty">show beauty box</p>
<span class="short">
    <div class="tooltip-beauty-box">Some Text</div>
</span> 
</li>

<li>
<img src="">
<p class="price">8999</p>
<p class="tooltip-beauty">show beauty box</p>
<span class="short">
    <div class="tooltip-beauty-box">Some Text</div>
</span> 
</li>
</ul>
```